# Erro na aplicação da função BoxCox do pacote MASS

Tags: r

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao utilizar a função `boxcox()` do pacote `MASS`:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

Não entendi como resolve-lo, segue meu script:

```
df <- read.table("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/teste.txt",header = TRUE)
names(df)[1:4] <- c("a","b","rep","y")
str(df)
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
df$b <- as.factor(df$b)
# análise de variância 
m0 <- aov(y~a*b, data=df)
summary(m0)
# checagem das pressuposições
par(mfrow=c(2,2)); plot(m0); layout(1)
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# testes
shapiro.test(residuals(m0))
bartlett.test(residuals(m0)~interaction(df$b,df$a)) 
car::leveneTest(m0) 
car::leveneTest(m0, center="mean")
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# precisa-se de tranformação para normalidade e homocedasticidade
require(MASS)
boxcox(m0)
```

Comment: Antes disso, talvez tenha um outro problema: `> min(df$y)
[1] -0.02980628`. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/47297/205888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além do modelo ajustado aos dados, é preciso informar à função `MASS::boxcox` onde estes dados estão armazenados:

```
boxcox(m0, data = df)
Error in boxcox.default(m0, data = df) : 
  response variable must be positive
```

Mas veja que o R nos dá uma mensagem de erro. Isso ocorre porque a transformação de Box-Cox não está definida para zero e números negativos, mas a tua variável resposta está assumindo exatamente um valor inferior a zero:

```
summary(df$y)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.02981 14.55843 21.65648 18.96480 25.39923 28.93967
sum(df$y < 0)
[1] 1
```

Desta forma, eu me perguntaria se este valor pode existir neste contexto. Afinal, são 259 observações e apenas uma é negativa. Como não sei absolutamente nada a respeito da origem destes dados, eu acho isso estranho. Mas pode ser que esta observação faça sentido sim e aí outra transformação deverá ser aplicada nos dados. Sugiro pesquisar sobre a transformação de Yeo-Johnson.

Comment: Marcus, aproveitando a oportunidade, eu comecei a tentar responder pela análise exploratória. Fiz um `filter` dos valores para `df$a` para saber quando os dados observados não atendiam a H0 do shapiro. Vc sabe me dizer se isso estaria certo ou devo considerar todos os `y` para o shapiro? Como resultado, quando `a` de `1:7` e `9`, pvalor <= 0.05.

Comment: Tem que considerar todos os `y`. Se não for assim, é possível ir eliminando observações "problemáticas" dos dados que analisamos e transformar qualquer conjunto de dados em uma variável com distribuição normal.

Comment: Valeu! obrigado pela info.

Comment: Obrigado Marcus e demais colegas! Vou ver o porque deste valor negativo!

Comment: Após retirar a linha do valor negativo e usar a função `boxcox()` da forma correta, recebi um valor de lambda=0.6. Porém, após a transformação, usando boxcox ou Yeo-Johnson, os dados continuam apresentando fuga da normalidade e heterocedasticidade.

Comment: Talvez ANOVA não seja o modelo adequado para estes dados, com transformação ou não na variável resposta. Pode ser que estes dados nunca consigam respeitar as suposições sobre os resíduos. Tente utilizar um método não-paramétrico.